# Understand marginal likelihood of mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, likelihood, lme4-nlme

I am reading a bit about mixed models  but I am unsure over the terms used and quite how they go together.
Pinheiro, on pg 62 of his book 'Mixed-effects models in S and S-Plus', describes the likelihood function.

[image]

The first term of the second equation is described as the conditional density of $\mathbf{y_i}$, 
and the second the marginal density of $\mathbf{b_i}$.

I have been trying to generate these log-likelihoods (ll) for simple random effect models, as I thought it would help my understanding, but I must be misinterpreting the derivations.

---

An example of where I have tried to calculate the ll's.

**example model**

```
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(angle  ~ temp + (1|replicate), data=cake, REML=FALSE)
```

**conditional log-likelihood**

I try to calculate the conditional log-likelihood for this model: it seems from $p(y_i \mid b_i, \beta, \sigma^2)$
that I should be able to calculate this by finding the density of the data at the predictions at the unit/replicate level.

```
sum(dnorm(cake$angle,
          predict(model), # predictions at replicate unit (XB + Zb) level
          sd=sigma(model),
          log=TRUE))
#[1] -801.6044

# Which seems to agree with
cAIC4::cAIC(model)$loglikelihood
# [1] -801.6044

# or should we really be using a multivariate normal density
# but doesn't make a difference as variance is \sigma^2 I_n
dmvnorm(cake$angle, predict(model), diag(sigma(model)^2,270, 270), log=TRUE)
#[1] -801.6044
```

**marginal log-likelihood**

I try to calculate the marginal log-likelihood, which `lme4` gives as

```
logLik(model)
#'log Lik.' -834.1132 (df=4)
```

Taking a similar approach as before it seems from $p(y_i \mid \beta, \theta, \sigma^2)$
that I should be able to calculate this by finding the density of the data at the  predictions at the population level, but it is not close.

```
sum(dnorm(cake$angle,
          predict(model, re.form=NA), # predictions at population (XB) level
          sd=sigma(model),
          log=TRUE))
# [1] -1019.202
```

So perhaps I need to use the second equation and need to use the conditional model for **y** and the marginal for **b**, but still not close.

```
sum(
  dnorm(cake$angle, predict(model), sd=sigma(model), log=TRUE) , # conditional
  dnorm(0,  ranef(model)$replicate[[1]], # RE predictions
            sd=sqrt(VarCorr(model)$replicate), log=TRUE) 
  ) 
# [1] -849.6086
```

Edit: Next go...

For the linear mixed model $Y = X\beta + Zb + \epsilon$, $b_i \sim N(0, \psi)$ and $e_i \sim N(0, \Sigma)$ I thought perhaps the variance for the likelihood calculation should be estimated as var(Y) = $Z\psi Z^T + \Sigma$, but wrong again!

So in code

```
z = getME(model, "Z")
zt =  getME(model, "Zt")
psi = bdiag(replicate(15, VarCorr(model)$replicate, simplify=FALSE))

betw = z%*%psi%*%zt
err = Diagonal(270, sigma(model)^2)
v = betw + err

sum(dnorm(cake$angle,
      predict(model, re.form=NA), 
      sd=sqrt(diag(v)),
      log=TRUE))
# [1] -935.652
```

My question:

- Can you tell me where I went wrong in calculating the marginal likelihood. I am not really needing code to reproduce the ll but more a description of why the approach I tried does not work.

Many thanks.

PS. I did look at the function that generates these values, `lme4:::logLik.merMod` and `lme4:::devCrit` and see the authors use some difficult / technical approach, which again leads to me needing help why my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce the marginal log-likelihood returned by `lme4:::logLik.merMod` by realising that the marginal distribution of **Y** is multivariate normal (MVN) (as the marginal distribution of **b** and the conditional of **Y** are MVN).

So this code will reproduce

```
library(mvtnorm)
dmvnorm(cake$angle, predict(model, re.form=NA), as.matrix(v), log=TRUE)
#[1] -834.1132
```

where `cake$angle` are the observations, `predict(model, re.form=NA)` are the population predictions (calculated using the fixed effect coefficients), and `v` is the variance of the marginal model (as shown in question).

---

A couple of comments on the failing efforts in my question.

When calculating the *conditional log-likelihood* I used the univariate normal density function, whereas I could/should of used the multivariate. In this case it doesn't make a difference as within unit variance is $\sigma^2 I_n$

```
mvtnorm::dmvnorm(cake$angle, predict(model), diag(sigma(model)^2,270, 270), log=TRUE)
#[1] -801.6044
```

Trying to calculate the *marginal distribution*

- First try used the predictions at population (XB) level but the incorrect variance (it ignored the between unit error)

  ```
  sum(dnorm(cake$angle, predict(model, re.form=NA), sd=sigma(model), log=TRUE))
  ```
- Second try was just nonsense *I think*
- Third try uses the univariate rather than multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could update your answer with an example of how to hand-calculate the marginal LL of a binomial GLMM? I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @blokeman; nope sorry . From your [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381085/calculating-log-likelihood-of-logistic-adaptive-quadrature-glmm-for-comparison-w) (I searched for the answer after I tried it the same naive way as you without success) it seems not in a closed form. And confirmed by [Ben Bolker ; "It is indeed true that closed-form expressions are not available for the log-likelihood"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499269/different-estimates-for-mixed-effects-logistic-regression-and-pwrssupdate-error)