Manually calculate loglikelihood of fitted model
My goal is to calculate the loglikelihood of a fitted model on some unseen data.
To this end I defined a function that calculates the loglikelihood by hand on some new data. However, as a sanity check I compared the outcome of the newly defined function to that of the existing logLik() function and the results do not match. Could someone explain me where I went wrong?
library("lme4")
# create a dataset
set.seed(123)
n <- 20000

TRT <- rnorm(n, mean = 336.59, sd = 244.09)
zipf <- rnorm(n, mean = 5.83, sd = 1.22)
word_length <- rnorm(n, mean = 4.69, sd = 2.31)
surprisal <- rnorm(n, mean = 5.04, sd = 2.92)
word_sent_index <- as.factor(sample(2:26, n, replace = TRUE))
participant_ID <- as.factor(sample(1:40, n, replace = TRUE))
word_token <- as.factor(sample(1:828, n, replace = TRUE))

df <- data.frame(TRT, zipf, word_length, word_sent_index, surprisal, participant_ID, word_token)

# split the dataset into train and test set
Nfolds <- 5
df$folds <- sample(1:Nfolds, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
fold = 5

train_data <- df[df$folds != fold, ]
test_data <- df[df$folds == fold, ]

# function to compute the log-likelihood on a new dataset using a fit lme4 model.
logLik_test <- function(lm, test_X, test_y) {
  predictions <- predict(lm, test_X,  re.form = ~(1 | participant_ID) + (1 | word_token), allow.new.levels = TRUE)
  stdev <- sigma(lm)
  loglik <- sum(dnorm(test_y, predictions, stdev, log=TRUE))
  return(loglik)
}

Next I fit a mixed effects model on the train_data and compare the output of the logLik function to the previously defined logLik_test() and using the train_data to evaluate the fit.
TRT_surprisal <- lmer(TRT ~
                        1 + zipf + word_length + word_sent_index + surprisal +
                        (1 | participant_ID) + (1 | word_token), train_data, REML = FALSE)
logLik(TRT_surprisal)
[1] 'log Lik.' -111093 (df=31)

logLik_test(TRT_surprisal, train_data, train_data$TRT)
[1] -111063.7

The two values do not match and I can't figure out why.
I also tried the solution provided in response to this question but I still get two different results. Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance!

You're missing the fact that the log-likelihood of the mixed model also has a component from the random effects. Section 3.4 of the lmer vignette tells you exactly how to compute the log-likelihood of the mixed model, but the math could be a little intimidating ...

The hard part of answering this question in a satisfying way is figuring out how to reduce the integral in the definition ($\int {\cal L}(y|\beta, b) \cdot {\cal L}(b|\Sigma(\theta)) , db$) in a way that is reasonably computationally efficient but also understandable, for the simple case here where the $b$ values are all independent ...

See if you can adapt the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271903/understand-marginal-likelihood-of-mixed-effects-models
